# rediect facebook app on canvas to mobile web app for mobile users

Tags: redirect, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas, mobile-website

How can i redirect users coming to my app on facebook (canvas app) to the mobile version of the same..

i know that can be achieved using this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

But how can i achieve this without putting a redirect code on the link published....

Is there any way by which facebook automatically redirects mobile users coming on canvas app to its mobile web version.....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NO need to use the above code ...just also fill in the mobile web url on facebook app setting page.
facebook will automatically redirect mobile users (iphone, ipad and other smartphone users) to your mobile website instead of canvas ...

Comment: Could You, please include a screenshot, or a description of "fill in the mobile web url on facebook app setting page" ? Thank You in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm also trying to work out how to do this, but I found a neat tutorial on the Facebook developers channel that might point you in the right direction.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/